# syntax for user-defined function which uses strsplit internally

Tags: r, syntax, user-defined-functions, strsplit

I am writing a utility function to do some data format conversion, and I am having trouble stating it correctly, so that it applies to the data I want it to apply to, and returns a result of the right shape.

I have a test data set called HiRawTiny, the str demonstrated below. The data in V1 is char. I have a test function called GetRank, whose job is to take all chars to the right of a ":" and coerce them to numeric. This is also demonstrated below. The list of list syntax I used in the fn to get at the output of strsplit is a bit opaque to me, and I frankly I arrived at it by trial and error, but it appears to work ok when passed single values. But when I pass it a vector (a data frame column), it doesn't give me a vector result that's the same length as the vector I passed it, but only a single value.

What should I do to sort this out? I am new to R (though I used to use S many decades ago), and suspect I've got into a syntax muddle. Is my function syntax wrong given what I am trying to do?  Should I be looking at using "apply" or one of its friends, to do this? Or should the fn be able to handle vector in/vector out natively?

```
str(HiRawTiny)

>'data.frame':  10 obs. of  7 variables:  
>$ V1: chr  "RANK:1" "RANK:2" "RANK:3" "RANK:4" ...  
$ V2: chr 
> "SOURCEID:CWC02001632398F4C" "SOURCEID:CWC020000F0D57DD6"
> "SOURCEID:CWC0200214C29872E" "SOURCEID:CWC0200163206B9F2" ...  
$ V3:
> chr  "TIME:01:04:2012-22:23:58" "TIME:01:04:2012-12:07:55"
> "TIME:01:04:2012-12:39:51" "TIME:02:04:2012-07:18:25" ...  
$ V4: chr 
> "SCORE:3142" "SCORE:3040" "SCORE:2911" "SCORE:2882" ...  
$ V5: chr 
> "TIEBREAK:4923864" "TIEBREAK:5787094" "TIEBREAK:766764"
> "TIEBREAK:1872936" ...  
$ V6: chr  "" "" "" "" ...  
$ V7: chr  "" ""
> "" "" ...

 GetRank function(x) {as.numeric(strsplit(x, split=":")[[1]][2]) }

GetRank(HiRawTiny[1,1]) [1] 1
GetRank(HiRawTiny[2,1]) [1] 2
GetRank(HiRawTiny[,1]) [1] 1

#"What I want is a vector of GetRank being applied to all of column 1
```

Comment: Hint: next time, try pasting the output of `dput(HiRawTiny)`. We can read that directly into our R session. Makes helping you a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks! Will do.  My console session paste always ends up very messy, spent 20 min making a hash of it in different ways,all hints and tips welcome.

Comment: The root of my problem was that I couldn't figure out how to design an expression that indexed into a list of lists result so as to produce a vectorisable result.  The direction I've taken, tactically, is to forgo the use of strsplit and instead use other, vectorised, string manipulation functions.  

This is because I need to scale, and (rightly or wrongly) I am cautious about the wiggle room required by of the other solutions.  These solutions really gave interesting insight into more advanced ways to use the language, though!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` returs a `list`. Each element of the `list` contains the divided string. You can change the `list` into a `matrix` with `do.call` and `rbind` and then select the second column,

```
GetRank <- function(x) {as.numeric(do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, split=":"))[, 2]) }

GetRank(HiRawTiny$V1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a much saner (and dimensionally scalable) way to index into the strsplit result (which is a list of lists).  Also I was unaware of the need to coerce the list result via do.call and rbind - hoped it would happen by magic.  (Which I think R tries to do when it can, but I shouldn't rely on.)  Saved me a question ;-)

Comment: Becasuse it's a list, and rbind doesn't know how to deal with a list. At least not in the way we want it to do. `do.call` makes a function call which is the equivalent of `rbind(alist[[1]], alist[[2]], ..., alist[[lenght(alist)]])`

Answer (score 3):

Just another way (Using @Stephan's `foo`):

```
# split by strsplit, results in a list with the 2nd element of 
# each element of the list always being the number you want.
# so pick it up using sapply with "[[" and convert it to numeric
> as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(foo, ":"), "[[", 2))
```

Comment: Interesting.  How does "[[" denote a function?  And is 2 the arg to that function?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Check out `?'[['` and also `?InternalMethods` and maybe also `getS3method("[[", "data.frame")`.

Comment: Pull one thread and the whole language comes tumbling out...;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to `unlist` the result of `strsplit` and then extract those entries that are of interest to you.

```
foo <- paste("RANK:",1:10,sep="")
GetRank <- function(x) {
  as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,":"))[seq(2,2*length(x),by=2)])
}
GetRank(foo)
```

Try feeding your data to the function bit-by-bit and tracing what happens in each successive step.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks!  And will report back when I'm unmuddled.  I was trying to do something like unlist by double-indexing into the result of strsplit - but I think if I stick with my original forumulation I need to unconstrain one of the indices.

Comment: Stephan - Sorry, I can only indicate one accepted answer officially.  Which isn't very "R" as there is always more than one way to do something ;-)  I chose the other one as it is closer to my original attempt and thus easier for me to get my head round.  But if there is a way to accept 2 answers do tell me. ta

Comment: No problem. @Luciano's solution is prettier, anyway ;-)